# Window function within group by in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions

I need a count for each user for every time the action field has been changed to the value 1. If the first entry is 1 that counts as well. The rows are out of order but should be counted in order by action_date.

In other words, what I believe needs to be done is: group the rows by user_id, order them by timestamp, and then count how often action=1 and action != the previous row.

**Example**

```
create table t (
user_id int,
action_date timestamp,
action int
);

Insert into t(user_id, action_date, action)
values
(1, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 1),
(2, '2017-01-01 00:00:00', 0),
(1, '2017-01-03 00:00:00', 1),
(2, '2017-01-03 00:00:00', 0),
(1, '2017-01-02 00:00:00', 1),
(2, '2017-01-02 00:00:00', 1),
(1, '2017-01-04 00:00:00', 1),
(2, '2017-01-04 00:00:00', 1);
```

The result should be

```
 user_id | count 
---------+-------
       1 |     1
       2 |     2
```

With help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770635/count-where-column-changes-to-specific-value-in-postgres) answer I can get the results for a single account this way,

```
select user_id, count(*)
from (select user_id, action_date,action,lag(action) over(order by action_date) as prev_action
      from t where user_id=2
     ) t
where (action<>prev_action and action=1) or (action=1 and prev_action is null)
group by user_id;
```

but am stuck trying to expand it to all users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `lag()` function with `partition by`:

```
select user_id, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             lag(action) over (partition by user_id order by action_date) as prev_action
      from t
     ) t
where (action = 1) and (prev_action is distinct from 1)
group by user_id;
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when I try this ```ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3:              lag(action) over (partition by user_id order by...```

Comment: Thank you very much for that elegant answer, it works perfectly.